# Spring boot admin behind firewall

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I have a spring-boot client app deployed in a customer network and I want to use SBA as a GUI for its actuator endpoints. I cannot use [register-client-applications](http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#register-client-applications) to register the app, mainly because the client app has no connectivity to SBA (its behind a firewall).

Is there a way how to add a client to SBA manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can add use a static configuration for spring cloud's discovery client. So there is no need that the client reach the sba server. See http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#spring-cloud-discovery-static-config